# What is the best way to create a key mold farm

Tags: terraria, terraria-console

I've seen people asking about how to get key molds, and they've been told the best way is an afk farm. I know you can have battle potions water candles and have a blood moon; but how exactly would I go about creating one of these?

I already have The Scourge of the Corrupter and The Rainbow Gun, and would now like The Vampire Knives. I need a farm as I don't want to walk around killing monsters for hours.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Recipe for key mold farm:

- Use you rolling pin until you make sure that you got a really good flatten surface.
- Spread Crimson all over the place.
- Get 200ml of Battle Potion and a Water Candle.
- Put some Jungle Temple traps to your taste. Dart and Spike Balls prefered.
- Make a cool wall to avoid the jumping enemies going to where you are and not being hit by your own traps.
- You can repeat the process to have 2 floor of enemies walking to their deaths.

**Note**: Make sure that you have no holes/caves beneath you, otherwise some mobs spawns will be lost, just because there's a stupid mob where you can't see.